# Visual Studio NO reconoce referencias

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs

Ayer que descargué la versión del proyecto de mi empresa en mi laptop (por TFS desde el VS) e intenté compilar; me salen bastantes errores.... lógicamente incoherentes, el proyecto está bastante estable y en constante mantenimiento.

Les comparto una Captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la captura se ve que el espacio de nombres ´Utilidades´ no es reconocido, a pesar de tener correctamente la referencia al DLL. Y así con casi todas las referencias de otros proyectos...

De antemano muchas gracias por su atención!

Comment: Asegurate de que las rutas de las dll sean las mismas que la que estan en las referencias (no estarán en una ruta de red por ejemplo en el trabajo?) Puedes probar tambien a eliminar la referencia y volver a añadirla a ver si eso soluciona el problema

Comment: Qué tal, eso es lo primero que intente hacer, quite todas las referencias y las volví a asignar pero no funcionó (las referencias originales son relativas); chequé que el TFS no me cambiara la versión de los proyectos pero no, todas son versión 4.0. Aún no encuentro que está causando este problema.

Comment: En que lugar fisico esta el assemly de Utilidades.dll? esta en la misma carpeta del proyecto? se versionan los assemblies?

Comment: Asegúrate de que la plataforma de la solución sea la indicada (x86 o Debug), Propiedades de la solución, luego puedes chequear la Ruta de Salida de cada aplicación/solución sea la correcta ya que sino no te encontrará la referencia.